# Jquery Draggable not positioning scrollbars properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need to make an image viewer that allows large images to be loaded into a container and then dragged within the container so that the entire image is viewable but the image is never dragged out of bounds. The below code works perfectly except the scrollbars are not accurately synchronizing with the position of the dragged image and allow the image to be scrolled out of bounds. How can I synchronize the scroll bars with the image while it is being dragged?

Edit:

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/GNv3T/8) is a working example

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            .container{margin: auto;cursor: move;width: 80%; position: relative; min-width:885px;}
            #screen{overflow:auto; width: 80%; height: 600px; clear: both; border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCCC; float:left; margin-right: 15px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
          <div class="container">
                <div id="screen">
                    <img class="drag-image" id="draggable" />
                </div>
          </div>
    </body>
    </html>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            $('#draggable').attr('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/uPjIz.jpg').load(function () {
                CreateDraggablePicture();
            });

        });

        function CreateDraggablePicture() {

            var x = ($('#draggable').width() - $('#screen').width() - $('#screen').offset().left) * -1;
            var y = ($('#draggable').height() - $('#screen').height() - $('#screen').offset().top) * -1;
            var x2 = $('#screen').offset().left;
            var y2 = $('#screen').offset().top;

            $("#draggable").draggable({ containment: [x, y, x2, y2], scroll: true });

        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Is your script outside the <html> tag on purpose? or is this just to depict an external js file?

Comment: @Eran It's just there to depict an external js file

Comment: Thanks, I tried playing around in JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/GNv3T/8/) and couldn't get it to work either, but there is a nice plugin that does it pretty well, so I gave up the urge to try and find a JQuery UI only solution...

Comment: Perhaps what I am asking for just isn't possible with Jquery Draggable? Seems a little bizarre that it would include a "scroll" option if that were the case.

Comment: I'm afraid so, the scroll option is if you want to drag something outside the bounds of the container, so it will scroll for you toward the  target in case the target is outside the bounds of the visible scroll area (e.g. for sortable of a very long list, you need it to move the top item to the bottom if the bottom is way below the visible area of the window)

Comment: Do need to have the scrollbar? it's not going to ever work w/ the native scroll bars because you are changing the position of the element in the div.  Unless you create your own scroll bars or control the scroll  position instead of the image position. SCroll Sync below looks pretty promising...

Comment: @Richard, if the SCroll Sync plugin can handle the scrollbars properly shouldn't JQuery handle them properly as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These plugins seems to do the same effect you describe here

- http://www.azoffdesign.com/overscroll (seems to be the best one)
- http://hitconsultants.com/dragscroll_scrollsync/scrollpane.html (I didn't find the download link though)
- http://the-taylors.org/jquery.kinetic/ (didn't see an option for scrollbars, but it's mobile friendly)

Comment: Thanks for this. This gives me an alternative and if I get no other answers I will award it to you. At this point, I am just curious why the JQuery Draggable plugin does not sync the scrollbars like the plugin you provided.

Comment: I'm following this question, I will be very happy to see a draggable solution, or at least a good explanation why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem with a similar jQuery plugin.  I eventually had to figure out and manually modify the plugin's math.  I believe the secret was that it was missing css margins or css padding from the calculation.

See if that helps

Comment: Do you have a GH fork request for the fix?